# What does this regular expression mean?

Tags: regex

```
/\ATo\:\s+(.*)/
```

Also, how do you work it out, what's the approach?

Comment: This is a good source to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start from left and look for any escaped (ie `\A`) characters. The rest are normal characters. `\A` means the start of the input. So `To:` must be matched at the very beginning of the input. I think the `:` is escaped for nothing. `\s` is a character group for all spaces (tabs, spaces, possibly newlines) and the `+` that follows it means you must have one or more space characters. After that you capture all the rest of the line in a group (marked with `( )`).

If the input was

```
To:   progo@home
```

the capture group would contain `"progo@home"`

Comment: `\A` is not the same as `^`. It will match only once when using the `m` modifier...

Answer (score 4):

In multi-line regular expressions, `\A` matches the start of the string (and `\Z` is end of string, while `^`/`$` matches the start/end of the string or the start/end of a line). In single line variants, you just use `^` and `$` for start and end of string/line since there is no distinction.

`To` is literal, `\:` is an escaped `:`.

`\s` means whitespace and the `+` means one or more of the preceding "characters" (white space in this case).

`()` is a capturing group, meaning everything in here will be stored in a "register" that you can use. Hence, this is the meat that will be extracted.

`.*` simply means any non newline character `.`, zero or more times `*`.

So, what this regex will do is process a string like:

```
To: paxdiablo
Re: you are so cool!
```

and return the text `paxdiablo`.

As to how to learn how to work this out yourself, the [Perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)<sup>(a)</sup> is a good start, and then practise, practise, practise :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You haven't actually stated which regex implementation you're using but most modern ones are very similar to Perl. If you can find a specific tutorial for your particular flavour, that would obviously be better.

Answer (score 2):

`\A` is a zero-width assertion and means "Match only at beginning of string".

The regex reads: On a line beginning with "To:" followed by one or more whitespaces (`\s`), capture the remainder of the line (`(.*)`).

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know what the different *character classes* and quantifiers are. Character classes are the backslash-prefixed characters, `\A` from your regex, for instance. Quantifiers are for instance the `+`. There are several references on the internet, for instance [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Using that, we can see what happens by going left to right:

- `\A` matches a beginning of the string.
- `To` matches the text "To" literally
- `\:` escapes the ":", so it loses it's special meaning and becomes "just a colon"
- `\s` matches whitespace (space, tab, etc)
- `+` means to match the previous class one or more times, so `\s+` means one or more spaces
- `()` is a capture group, anything matched within the parens is saved for later use
- `.` means "any character"
- `*` is like the `+`, but zero or more times, so `.*` means any number of any characters

Taking that together, the regex will match a string beginning with "To:", then at least one space, and the anything, which it will save. So, with the string "To: JaneKealum", you'll be able to extract "JaneKealum".

Comment: `+` is not a modifier, it is a *quantifier*. Modifiers are the flags you put after the expression, like `i`, `g`, etc.

Comment: That's true, confused the terminology. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

It matches `To:` at the beginning of the input, followed by at least one whitespace, followed by any number of characters as a group.

Answer (score 0):

The initial and trailing `/` characters delimit the regular expression.

A `\` inside the expression means to treat the following character specially or treat it as a literal if it normally has a special meaning.

The `\A` means match only at the beginning of a string.

`To` means match the literal "To"

`\:` means match a literal ':'. A colon is normally a literal and has no special meaning it can be given.

`\s` means match a whitespace character.

`+` means match as many as possible but at least one of whatever it follows, so `\s+` means match one or more whitespace characters.

The `(` and `)` define a group of characters that will be captured and returned by the expression evaluator.

And finally the `.` matches any character and the `*` means match as many as possible but can be zero. Therefore the `(.*)` will capture all characters to the end of the input string.

So therefore the pattern will match a string that starts "To:" and capture all characters that occur after the first succeeding non-whitespace character.

The only way to really understand these things is to go through them one bit at a time and check the meaning of each component.